# With Subversion, Is there a way to add a WC inside another WC?

Tags: svn

Say I have a WC, 1, that has another WC, 2, in it: e.g.

Structure:

```
/1
  /.svn
  /2
    /.svn
```

Where 2 is checked out from a different repo entirely (not a sync/mirror)

Is there a way to do `svn add 2` without getting the message:

```
svn: warning: W150002: '/1/2' is already under version control
svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

Currently I'm just renaming `.svn` to `@svn` pre add.

Comment: It seems you're trying to replicate externals without actually using externals, but not quite because externals are still linked to the original repository. What are you trying to do exactly with 2? I presume you want to receive further updates but where do you want custom changes to go?

Answer (score 1):

If you want *really* merge `wc-2` into `wc-1` you should `export` `wc-2` from repository:

```
svn export svn://wc-2
svn add wc-2
svn commit wc-2
```

In this case you lose the connection the `wc-2` repository so you can't update it when it has new commits.

If you want update it inside your `wc-1` working copy you want to read about [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html):

> Sometimes it is useful to construct a working copy that is made out of
>   a number of different checkouts. For example, you may want different
>   subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository or
>   perhaps from different repositories altogether. You could certainly
>   set up such a scenario by hand—using svn checkout to create the sort
>   of nested working copy structure you are trying to achieve. But if
>   this layout is important for everyone who uses your repository, every
>   other user will need to perform the same checkout operations that you
>   did.
>
> Fortunately, Subversion provides support for externals definitions. An
>   externals definition is a mapping of a local directory to the URL—and
>   ideally a particular revision—of a versioned directory.